# How to swap the active image bake for multiple objects

Tags: texture-baking

I'm currently working on a model in blender I plan on baking the ambient occlusion normal maps and textures. But for each map I want to bake I have to manually select each part of the mesh and change it to the desired image to bake onto. Is there any way I can assign an image to all of them at once without having to manually swap them?

Comment: I guess that you use Blender Cycles engine. In this case, I think this is not possible. Cycles baking is done into image which must be present in the node tree for each material. There is [Bake Tool addon](https://cgcookiemarkets.com/all-products/baketool/) which *probably* speeds up this behaviour, it's paid though. So by default you add image texture node for each material, you can `Ctrl`+`C` > `Ctrl`+`V` them.

Comment: I was using blender render.